# Create PHP associative array with any number of associations

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am writing code that reads in .csv files and creates associative arrays in PHP.  I want to organize the array such that each column (in order) before the last column is a level of an associative array.  In the non-generalized case:

```
$data = array();
$file =fopen("data.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE)  {
    $var1 = $line[0];
    $var2 = $line[1];
    $value = $line[2];
    $data[$var1][$var2] = $value;
}
```

I want to be able to do this regardless of the number of columns there are (ie, var1... varN). It will be organized such that variables (columns) 1-N uniquely identify each row, and the desired value is always the last columns.

Comment: Have you considered to create a `recursive function` to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just put another `while` inside your `while` considering how much columns are in that line you took from the file. That should be enough.

Comment: Not sure I understand... How do you to write the line $data[$var1][$var2]...[$varN] = $value.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by building the line of code and using the eval statement:

```
        $str = '$allData["data"]';
        for($x=0; $x<$numVars; $x++) {
            $var = $line[$x];
            if(($x+1) != $numVars) {
                $str .= "['$var']";
            }
        }
        $str .= "=";
        $str .= $line[$numVars-1];
        $str .= ";";
        eval($str);
```